# How do you create an index for unique variables in sas?

Tags: variables, indexing, unique, sas

I am trying to combine the odds ratios outputted from two models with different adjustments in SAS:

i.e:

```
ods output oddsratios=adjustedOR1(rename=(OddsRatioEst=OR1);
 proc logistic data=dataname; 
      model y= b d c a e; run;

ods output oddsratios=adjustedOR2 (rename=(OddsRatioEst=OR2);
 proc logistic data=dataname; 
      model y= b d c; run;
```

proc sort.....

```
data Oddsratios (keep=Effect OR1 OR2);
merge adjustedOR1 adjustedOR2; by effect; run;
```

Problem is that if I sort and merge by the Effect variable, I lose the order in which I put the explanatory variables in the model.

Is there anyway to assign an index to the variable according to the order I put it in the model, so that the final table will have the effect column in the order: b d c a e?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a new sequence variable in your "primary" dataset with the sort order you want. then re-sorting the merged result by that variable:

```
data adjustedOR1;
   set adjustedOR1;
   sortkey = _n_;
run;
proc sort data=adjustedOR1;
   by effect;
run;
proc sort data=adjustedOR2;
   by effect;
run;
data Oddsratios (keep=Effect OR1 OR2 sortkey);
   merge adjustedOR1 adjustedOR2; 
      by effect;
run;
proc sort data=Oddsratios;
  by sortkey;
run;
```

This would be a bit more generic than hard-coding the sort sequence as Keith suggests using PROC SQL (which also works by the way).

And thanks to Keith for providing a practical example!

Comment: Good answer Bob, I imagine it comes down to how many effects variables there are and in what further steps the data is used.  I always prefer to look at data rather than visualise it in my head, hence the example. (plus I know the solution I'm proposing works!)

Comment: Thanks Bob and Keith! I ended up using Bobs example as it was the quickest and because I had a mixture of continuous and categorical variables. But Keiths one would be good to modify for the macro I'm writing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to sort your data is to do the merge in Proc Sql and use a case statement in an 'order by' clause. Here is an example.

```
ods output oddsratios=adjustedOR1(rename=(OddsRatioEst=OR1));
 proc logistic data=sashelp.class; 
      model sex= height age weight; run;

ods output oddsratios=adjustedOR2 (rename=(OddsRatioEst=OR2));
 proc logistic data=sashelp.class; 
      model sex= height age; run;

proc sql;
create table Oddsratios as select
a.effect,
a.or1,
b.or2
from    adjustedOR1 as a 
            left join
        adjustedOR2 as b
            on a.effect=b.effect
order by 
    case a.effect
        when 'Height' then 1
        when 'Age' then 2
        when 'Weight' then 3
    end;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just change the order in which the variables appear in the data set, you can use the retain statement:

```
data Oddsratios (keep=Effect OR1 OR2);
 retain b d c a e;
 merge adjustedOR1 adjustedOR2; 
 by effect; 
run;
```

This isn't really what retain is for, but it works.

But I wonder why you care what the order of the variables in the data set is. You can specify the order when you display results with `proc print`, for example.

Comment: b,d,c,a,e are values of the variable 'Effect', rather than separate variable names.  I believe the question relates to custom sorting of a specific variable

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer I think that is still fairly flexible is to create an informat from your original dataset.  Then during the merge you can create a new variable with the numeric order variable and sort by that afterwards.

Another solution would be to merge in a fashion not requiring a sort - create a hash table, for example, or create a format out of the odds ratio 2 dataset and append it on in a simple data step rather than via merge.

```
data have;
input effect $;
datalines;
b
d
c
a
e
;;;;
run;

data for_format;
set have;
fmtname='EFF';
type='j';
hlo='s';
start=effect;
label=_n_;
keep hlo type fmtname start label;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_format;
quit;

proc sort data=have;
by effect;
run;

data want;
set have; *your merge here instead;
by effect;
eff_order=input(effect,$EFF.);
run;

proc sort data=want;
by eff_order;
run;
proc print data=want;
run;
```